# Trying to get the converted result from USD to EUO in javasctipt

Tags: javascript, html, logic

I am making a page on a website that will take in a users USD value and then convert it to EURO, using an onclick button command.
I can not get the onclick command to show the converted value.

```js
function usdtoeu() {
  let USD = document.getElementById("EX").innerHTML;
  var EUO = .92;
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = USD * EUO;

}
```

```html
<h1>Time to convert Usd to Euro</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="mathe">
  Enter USD: <input type="text" id="EX" size="10" />
  <p/>
  <input type="button" value="Get the converted rate" onclick=" usdtoeu()"> </br>
  </br>
  The rate is: <input type="text" id="sum" size="10" />
```

I think I am missing a printing value but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input>` elements don't have an `innerHTML`, they have a `value`:

```js
function usdtoeu() {
  let USD = document.getElementById("EX").value;
  var EUO = .92;
  document.getElementById("sum").value = USD * EUO;

}
```

```html
<h1>Time to convert Usd to Euro</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="mathe">
  Enter USD: <input type="text" id="EX" size="10" />
  <p/>
  <input type="button" value="Get the converted rate" onclick=" usdtoeu()"> </br>
  </br>
  The rate is: <input type="text" id="sum" size="10" />
```

Comment: solid, thanks I missed that, need more coffee.